# Linking to a file that starts with a dot (`.`) in Jekyll

Tags: html, hyperlink, jekyll

In an `index.html` for my Jekyll site, I try to link to each of these files.

```html
<a href="/files/foo.yml">foo.yml</a>
<a href="/files/.eslintrc">.esliintrc</a>
```

These files definitely exist under that path, but the 2nd link doesn't seem to work - it returns a 404.

Is there a special way to link to a file starting with a dot `.` ?

Comment: Hi try encoding the url, which means replace the `.` with `%2E`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that files starting in `dot` are not automatically supported

See [this issue thread](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7917).

The fix was adding my file to the `include:` list in `_config.yml`

```yaml
include:
  - .eslintrc
```